# Looking for a css property which will work on all the browsers if the condition is as follows

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a CSS property which will work on all the browsers if the condition is as follows:

1. If the text paragraph is without space, should be break & fit within the area in any browser.
2. The word should not be break in any browser.

(IE does not support `word-break` property, `-ms-word-break:normal;` property break the line & word)

PFB Image for illustration purpose

[image: image for illustration purpose]

Comment: Use `word-wrap` instead of `word-break`.

Comment: Thank you Muhammad, this worked. Actually, my "a" tag is in the two different divs, having parents with display:table; & child to display:table-cell; because my design was different & wanted my "a" tag should be vertically middle align, which is I changed now. I think word-wrap is not working with table property with my two conditions mentioned in the Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if text are inside a p tag then

```
p{
   word-warp: break-word;
   -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

That will work.

Answer (score 1):

as suggested in comments use `word-wrap: break-word;` this is what you need

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>

Looking for a csspropertywhichwillworkonall the browsers if the condition is as followsLooking for a css property which will onelongtext on all the browsers if the condition is as followsLooking for a css property which will work on all the browsers if the condition is as followsLooking for a csspropertywhichwillworkonall the browsers if the condition is as followsLooking for a css property which will work on all the browsers if the condition is as followsLooking for a css property which will work on all the browsers if the condition is as follows

</div>
```